# How to get value from specific key in NodeJS JSON

Tags: json, node.js

```
{
    "id": 83,
    "key": "hello",
    "en": "Hello",
    "mm": "This is greeting",
    "created_at": "2016-12-05T10:14:02.928Z",
    "updated_at": "2017-01-31T02:57:11.181Z"
}
```

I'm trying to get value from `mm` key in NodeJS. I've tried to get `translation["mm"]` but it does not work at all. Please help me how to get `mm` from above data.

My current node version is `5.11`

Comment: Is that JSON in an array? You may need to iterate that, then grab it (`translation[index]["mm"]`)

Comment: If it is a JavaScript Object (already parsed from a JSON string), you might be able to access the fields with `translation.mm` or `translation['mm']`. If it's a string, you should parse it first with `JSON.parse(string)`.

Comment: @mrlew he already is using `translation["mm"]` as you can see, there's another factor here we're not seeing.

Comment: @SterlingArcher sure, was just pointing that it should work **if** it's a  JavaScript Object.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Edited The Answer. Now Its working for above object in question**

You can use following function to access the keys of JSON. I have returned 'mm' key specifically.

```
    function jsonParser(stringValue) {

       var string = JSON.stringify(stringValue);
       var objectValue = JSON.parse(string);
       return objectValue['mm'];
    }
```

Comment: he already is using `translation["mm"]` which is correct, this does not answer the issue. The object does not need to be parsed either, it's already valid JSON

Comment: @SterlingArcher JSON always need to be parsed to JavaScript Object. JSON is a string notation.

Answer (score 17):

JSON is an interchange format, meaning it's only a text representing data in a format that many applications can read and translate into it's own language.

Therefore, using node.js you should parse it first (translate it to a javascript object) and store the result in a variable:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(yourJSONString);
```

Then, you can ask for any of it properties:

```
var mm = obj.mm;
```

Comment: indeed, it's a valid JSON. That's why i suggest to parse it first: to deal with an object instead of dealing with a JSON; since I don't know if it's another variable or anything else.

Comment: This provided the easiest and best explanation for me. Accepted answer didn't work.