# How to handle large JSON files in NodeJS and get specifc values out of them?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, typescript

I have a JSON file with over 3 million lines in my project and want to write a function that dynamically returns values from that file for a given key. The structure of the JSON is like so:

```
{
  "12345": {  // objects are identified by hash keys
    "objectProperty1": 12345,
    "objectProperty2": "bla",
    // ...
  },
  "67890": {
    "objectProperty1": 67890,
    "objectProperty2": "blub",
    // ...
  },
  // ...
}
```

I currently just import the entire file at the top of my code which makes starting the program take several minutes. I'd like to change that somehow.

Then I'd like to know how I can access specifc objects in that file. My function currently looks like this but it always returns `undefined` even when I'm sure that the passed key is in the JSON:

```
import * as jsonFile from './data.json';

const getObjectFromJsonFile = (key: number) => {
  const parsedFile = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsonFile));
  const keyAsString = key.toString();
  return parsedFile[keyAsString];
};
```

When I call this function with `getObjectFromJsonFile(12345)` I get `undefined`. What's wrong here?

Comment: People that had similar problems invented database systems. That is what you should use ;)

Comment: @DaDo This is a related article that may help you: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874096/parse-large-json-file-in-nodejs)

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsonFile))` this looks seriously fishy, and is most-likely a mistake. It seems to me that in order for this to work, `jsonFile` is already a JS object. "Quick" serialize-deserialize is costing you loads of time for nothing. For this to make sense, `const parsedFile = jsonFile;` must be equivalent to what you currently have.

Comment: Sorry, my original comment was thinking this was a react question, it's nodejs, just use [readFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback) instead of importing it and you should be fine.

Comment: @Adam how would I break up the JSON into smaller pieces?

Comment: @str I have a MongoDB database in my project. Should I try to load the JSON in there and then only query the DB for requested data?

Comment: @spender I get a TypeScript error when I try to do jsonFile[key], but after parsing it twice the error is gone. I got that from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41949494/13575631

Comment: @DaDo You definitely need to load these data to MongoDB.