# How to get the id from the given lines of code?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, object, hbs

```
{
  acknowledged: true,
  insertedId: new ObjectId("612d9d08db9c20f031033478")
}
```

This was the JSON format I got while I added a file and some other things to MongoDB and I want to get this id separately to save the file to another folder.

Can anyone please explain this?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this question was answered by Vikas in this thread [How to get value from specific key in NodeJS JSON [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41949461/how-to-get-value-from-specific-key-in-nodejs-json/41949492)

> **Edited The Answer. Now Its working for above object in question**
>
> You can use following function to access the keys of JSON. I have
> returned 'mm' key specifically.

```
function jsonParser(stringValue) {
 
        var string = JSON.stringify(stringValue);
        var objectValue = JSON.parse(string);
        return objectValue['mm'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if this is a JSON String, at first of all you have to parse it to object liertal, then you can access the specified property you mentioned, so you can do like the following:

```
function parseJsonString(jsonString) {
    // first parse it to object
    var obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
    // now access your object property/key
    var id = obj.insertedId;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If your doing it on mongodb shell or Robo3T then, the line of code would be:
`db.collection_name.find({},{insertedId:1})`
This is related to `projection`. `1` represents you want to display it as your output.

In your case as you want only the value of your object id to get displayed, you have to use `.valueOf()` ; that is `ObjectId().valueOf()`.

```
                     ->  insertedId: new ObjectId("612d9d08db9c20f031033478") 
                     ->  ObjectId("612d9d08db9c20f031033478").valueOf()
                     ->
                     ->  612d9d08db9c20f031033478
```

Your can refer this : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.valueOf/ site for your reference.

So you can use this `.valueOf()` in your code and get the `id` saved in the document